# I am getting exception errorn in for thread main java lang error

Tags: java

i am a beginner in Java and getting the error

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem: "

Below is the code:

```
public class Second {
    String Name;
    int age;

}

public class Seco {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Second display = new Second();
display.Name = "Gunwant";
display.age = 37;
System.out.println(display.age);
System.out.println(display.Name);
}
}
```

Comment: Your both class are in same file?

Answer (score 0):

hello satya you should put the class Seco in a file called Seco.java and the class Second in a file called Second.java or you remove 'public' from 'public class Second' like this :

```
 class Second {
    String Name;
    int age;

}

public class Seco {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Second display = new Second();
display.Name = "Gunwant";
display.age = 37;
System.out.println(display.age);
System.out.println(display.Name);
}
}
```

this way it should work